# System.Data.DataRowView, c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've got a problem:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT dbo.User.name FROM dbo.User", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
da.Fill(dt);
```

It returned `System.Data.DataRowView` in every row.

I tried:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "idUser";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "dbo.User.name"
```

and I get error:

> Cannot bind to the new display member. Parameter name:
>   newDisplayMember

I want to get `idUser` and `name`.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the ID in your SELECT statement and assign the DataTable as the DataSource after you have filled the DataTable:

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT IDUser, Name FROM dbo.User", con);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
```

You can then set up the ComboBox as such:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "IDUser";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to access the selected text or value of the item selected in the ComboBox, then you will need to do something like:

```
DataRowView drvItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

if (drvItem != null)
{
    label4.Text = drvItem["ID"].ToString();
    label3.Text = drvItem["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now i get idUser in rows. But still i can't display on secelct: 
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object personVal = comboBox1.DisplayMember;
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(personVal);
            object personSel = comboBox1.ValueMember;
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(personSel);
        }

Comment: @JanOlMajti I have updated the answer to show how you would access the selected item data.

Answer (score 4):

Please use below

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT IDUser, Name FROM dbo.User", con); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
da.Fill(dt);  
comboBox1.DataSource = dt; 
comboBox1.ValueMember = "IDUser";   
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```