# System.Data.DataRowView in combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am just Trying to insert the data into the Sql From Selecting the item From the combobox in windows form.
But after the insertion in the database is does not show the value of selected item but it shows ("System.Data.DataRowView").

my code of insertion Is.

FORM LOAD-

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CPP", con);
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        comboBox10.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox10.ValueMember = "Id";
        comboBox10.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

On the BUTTON CLICK EVENT-

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CPP (Name) values ('" + comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After the insertion of selective item.
It Shows In the database Table-("System.Data.DataRowView")

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try it in this order: ` comboBox10.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];    comboBox10.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox10.ValueMember = "Id";`

Comment: you can find answer in this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786637/system-data-datarowview-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below updated code.

```
var row = (DataRowView)comboBox10.SelectedItem;    
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into CPP (Name) values ('" + row["Name"].ToString() + "')", con);    
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set  [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and `ValueMember` properties accorrdingly.

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Foo";
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Bar";
```

If you don't specify these properties, a ListControl like ComboBox does not know what to display. So it displays just the type of the item as string (Type.FullName).

Comment: I am inserting  the name of selective item of combobox into the database not the item and value into combobox.