# What is causing a 'System.Data.DataRowView' error?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a listbox that is loaded from a SQL table. Here is the code:

```
 private void DisplaySubjects()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(zSQL_Variables.csNotebook);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT DISTINCT Subject,ID from Subjects", conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        this.lbxSubjects.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        this.lbxSubjects.DisplayMember = "Subject";
        this.lbxSubjects.ValueMember = "Subject"; 
        lblSubjectsCount.Text = "[" + lbxSubjects.Items.Count.ToString() + "]";
    }
```

The table loads correctly.  I have set up a drag and drop operation which takes an item from the listbox and drops it in a textbox. Instead of getting the selected field from the listbox I get  "System.Data.DataRowView" instead. Here is my code for the Drag and Drop operations.

```
 private void txtFindSubject_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }

    private void txtFindSubject_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFindSubject.Text = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
    }

    private void lbxSubjects_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lbxSubjects.DoDragDrop(lbxSubjects.SelectedItem.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
      
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I get "System.Data.DataRowView" instead of real values in my Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428542/why-i-get-system-data-datarowview-instead-of-real-values-in-my-listbox)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786637/system-data-datarowview-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortuntely it doesn't.

Comment: What type you get in lbxSubjects.SelectedItem ? And why you don't use SelectedValue?

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, it looks like you have the code in the (destination) text box events backwards in addition to Maxim’s comment. Try the changes below, they appear to work in my tests.

```
private void txtFindSubject_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  txtFindSubject.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString();
}
private void txtFindSubject_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void lbxSubjects_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  lbxSubjects.DoDragDrop(lbxSubjects.SelectedValue, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```